# How to wire Songle Relay Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am trying to connect this songle relay to the pins on my pi. I have attached the + on the relay to 5v (pin 2) and the - to grn (pin 6). I have the I attached to GPIO. 7 (BCM 4).

Here is my script (yes borrowed from someone online). I consider this to be a simple experiment (probably shouldn't say that since it is not working).

So basically at a minimum I would hope to hear the relay "click" indicating that something is happening. But I hear nothing. Is it possible my relay is just broken?

It is probably also possible that I have no idea what I am doing. In which case, please be kind.

```
# gpio_blink.py
# by Scott Kildall (www.kildall.com)

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

state = True

# endless loop, on/off for 6 seconds
while True:
 GPIO.output(4,True)
 time.sleep(6)
 GPIO.output(4,False)
 time.sleep(6)
```

Here is the output of gpio readall

[image]

[image: Songle Relay]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about hardware wiring are off-topic.

Comment: Don't include images of text--just copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out my wiring was correct. It appears my relay is just broken, not exactly sure how. The code however it turns out did not function as expected. Other forum posts also discussed similar problems.

It appears that toggling the high and low on the input on certain relay models still leaves a very small ~0.05 current flowing through the signal pin which apparently is enough to maintain the state of high. The way I got around this was toggling the `GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)` the setup of the pin to be `GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)` which then causes the expected relay behaviour.

So if your relay is acting abnormally it may be that the low on your signal pin is actually still high enough to maintain the state of the signal.